# Combining `OptionT` and `EitherT` to handle `Future[Either[Error, Option[T]]]`

Tags: scala, scalaz, scala-cats

I want to use Cats `EitherT` and `OptionT` to handle the type `Future[Either[Error, Option[T]]`. Suppose the following methods:

```
def findTeacher(id: Int): Future[Either[String, Option[Teacher]]]
def findSchool(teacher: Teacher): Future[Either[String, Option[School]]]
```

Now if I want to call them subsequently in a for-comprehension I can use `EitherT` and `OptionT` like this:

```
def getSchoolByTeacherId(id: Int): Future[Either[String, Option[School]]] = {
  val result = for {
    maybeTeacher <- EitherT(findTeacher(id))
    schoolF = maybeTeacher.map(findSchool).getOrElse(Future.successful(Right(None)))
    school <- EitherT(schoolF)
  } yield {
    school
  }

  result.value
}
```

I wonder if it's possible to make it more concise maybe by combining `OptionT` with `EitherT`?

Comment: What benefit would you expect from using `OptionT` too (which you do not use in your example)?

Comment: Just looking for more concise way instead of the second line of for-comprehension. Or maybe it can be rewritten in a different way using some methods or types of Cats that I'm not aware of (not necessarily using for-comprehension)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If understand your question correctly, you want to build a combined monad-transformer of `EitherT` and `OptionT`. Using Cats you may try something like this:

```
type FutureEither[X] = EitherT[Future, String, X]
type OResult[X] = OptionT[FutureEither, X]

object OResult {

  implicit def apply[A](value: Future[Either[String, Option[A]]]): OResult[A] = OptionT[FutureEither, A](EitherT(value))

  implicit class OResultOps[A](val value: OResult[A]) extends AnyVal {
    @inline
    def directValue: Future[Either[String, Option[A]]] = value.value.value
  }

}
```

And then you may re-write your `getSchoolByTeacherId` as

```
import OResult._
def getSchoolByTeacherId(id: Int): Future[Either[String, Option[School]]] = {
  val result = for {
    teacher <- OResult(findTeacher(id))
    school <- findSchool(teacher)
  } yield school

  result.directValue
}
```

Unfortunately, even though `OResult.apply` is `implicit` you still have to write it explicitly in the first line of your for-comprehension but this allows skipping it on the further lines.